# Having problem with rigify

Tags: rigify

Can anyone tell me how to append a character rigged with rigify properly from one blend file to another, cause I tried to append it and it's not working properly.

Comment: Did you group all the datablocks (mesh, rig) and appended the group? What do you mean with "not working properly? Which is the issue exactly?

Comment: Here is the blend file
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ySQuQ6HlKZ1PjbLz91z2ahWm_KcrdcGJ
this the file that I want to append but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

In object mode:

Select your armature and its child objects (you can right-click the armature in the outliner and choose "select hierarchy).
Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to create a group of your selection, give it the name you want via <kbd>F6</kbd> (like "character" or whatever's making sense).
Save the file.

Open the file where you need to append your character, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, navigate to your character's .blend file, go in its group folder and select your character's group.

It should work this way.
The last thing to do: since all the "WGT" objects are imported in the same layer as your character's rig and model and overlapping your rig, I suggest you use the outliner, select all "WGT" objects, and move them to another layer.